# I have a page which contains a combobox. so when I select one of the item in combobox and click the next button it should move to respective page

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I have a page which contains a combobox. Each item in the combobox have 3 page titles. so when I select one of the item from it and click next button it should move to respective page

Html file:

```
<ion-header>

<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>REGISTRATION</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<h1>Step 1 : Choose the category</h1>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="category">
        <ion-option value="i">Individual</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="t">3rd party</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="d">Dedicated</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<div *ngIf="category==='i'"><p>Show individual desc</p></div>
<div *ngIf="category==='t'"><p>Show 3rd Party desc</p></div>
<div *ngIf="category==='d'"><p>Show Dedicated desc</p></div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer no-shadow class="foot">
<ion-toolbar position="bottom">
    <button (click)="rg()" ion-button full color="primary" 
 block>Next</button>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, 
IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ObsAuthService } from '../../services/obs_auth.services';
import { ConnectrgPage} from '../connectrg/connectrg';
import { IndividualregPage } from '../individualreg/individualreg';

@Component({
selector: 'page-connectreg',
templateUrl: 'connectreg.html',
providers: [ObsAuthService]
})
export class ConnectregPage {


constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: ObsAuthService,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: 
 LoadingController) {}

    selectChange(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    public rg(){
        this.nav.push(IndividualregPage);
    }
 }
```

I have the respective page names in the combobox.